# InAppPurchase Android verify issue

Tags: android, oauth, google-api, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Sorry for my English, I have a problem trying to check the status of InApp, I am following all steps listed here for the authentication: https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/authorization, I have the access_token but when I want to check the status of InApp I use this URL: https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v1.1/applications/packageName/inapp/productId/purchases/token , And the answer I get is this:

```
 403 Forbidden 
 
- Show headers - 
  
{
  "error": {
   "errors": [
    {
     "domain": "global", 
     "reason": "forbidden" 
     "message": "Forbidden" 
    } 
   ] 
   "code": 403, 
   "message": "Forbidden" 
  } 
}
```

I donot which may be the error if someone could tell me is happening or help me would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you.

Comment: The same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I keep looking, I'll implement this: http://distriqt.uservoice.com/forums/199650-general/suggestions/5530250-in-app-purchase-validation

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to add permissions for your service account. In Google Play Developer console (https://play.google.com/apps/publish/) navigate to "Settings" -> "User Accounts and Rights". Click "Add new user" and enter the email address of your service user (something like  123456789-abcdefghijklm@developer.gserviceaccount.com). Then you grant read-only permissions, the Developer console recognizes automatically that it's a service user and the user is immediately added.

Unfortunately, for me the next step is a 400 "Invalid Value" response that seems to be a bug in Google's backend.

Comment: But what is the password for this account? I've already added to the panel but when I go to request permission, ask for a password and I will not put that.

Comment: For service accounts, it just tells me "user has been added". No invitation or password required.